# Como preencher um DropDownList a partir de outro DropDownList

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Preciso saber como faço para popular um DropDownList a partir de outro DropDownList. Exemplo: Tenho um DropDownList chamado Equipe que pega as informações do meu DB. Quando seleciono por exemplo "Equipe1" preciso que no meu segundo DropDownList carregue todos os integrantes daquela equipe. Todas essas informações estão no DB. Tenho 3 tabelas Equipe, Integrante e EquipedeIntegrantes.

**Buscar Integrante**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ListarIntegrantes(int id)
    {
        GerenciadorContexto ctx = new GerenciadorContexto();
        var lista = new List<EquipedeIntegrante>();

        try
        {
            lista = ctx.EquipedeIntegrantes.Where(m => m.EquipeId == id).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return Json(new { Resultado = lista }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**View**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {

      <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>TarefaViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EquipeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EquipeId, Model.Equipes, "--Selecione", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IntegranteId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select id="IntegranteId" class="form-control"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descricao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Conclusao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Conclusao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#EquipeId").change(function () {

        var value = $("#EquipeId option:selected").val();

        if (value !== 0 || value !== undefined)
        {
            ListarIntegrantes(value);
        }

    })

})

function ListarIntegrantes(value)
{

    var url = "/Tarefas/ListarIntegrantes";
    var data = { equipe: value };
    $("#EquipeId").empty();
    $.ajax({

        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        data: data
    }).done(function (data) {

        if (data.Resultado.length > 0) {
            var dadosGrid = data.Resultado;
            $("#EquipeId").append('<option value="">--Selecione</option>');

            $.each(dadosGrid, function (indice, item) {

                var opt = "";

                opt = '<option value="' + item["Id"] + '">' + item["Nome"] + '</option>';
            })
        }
    })

}
```

**Tabelas**

[image: Tabela EquipedeIntegrante]

[image: Integrante][image: Equipe]

Answer (score 1):

Ao colocar `var opt = "";` dentro do laço `.each`, a variável será *esvaziada* (e redeclarada) a cada iteração do objeto `dadosGrid`.

Coloque-a fora, e dentro do laço concatene a variável com a string que monta as `option`; e após isso, envie via `.append` o resultado:

```
if (data.Resultado.length > 0) {
   var dadosGrid = data.Resultado;
   $("#EquipeId").append('<option value="">--Selecione</option>');

   var opt = "";
   $.each(dadosGrid, function (indice, item) {
      opt += '<option value="' + item["Id"] + '">' + item["Nome"] + '</option>';
   })
   $("#EquipeId").append(opt);
}
```

Ou você pode fazer um `.append` só no final, concatenando tudo:

```
if (data.Resultado.length > 0) {
   var dadosGrid = data.Resultado;
   var opt = "";
   $.each(dadosGrid, function (indice, item) {
      opt += '<option value="' + item["Id"] + '">' + item["Nome"] + '</option>';
   })
   $("#EquipeId").append('<option value="">--Selecione</option>'+opt);
}
```

Comment: Continua retornando o mesmo erro amigo no console do navegador 
GET http://localhost:54446/Tarefas/ListarIntegrantes?equipe=1 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Mas na pergunta não cita nenhum erro :D  ... os únicos erros que vi foram os que coloquei na resposta. Se está dando erro de servidor, não é problema no JavaScript. Tem que saber que erro é esse do servidor. Provavelmente no arquivo `"/Tarefas/ListarIntegrantes"`.

Comment: Olhe acima o método ListarIntegrantes se possui algum erro por gentileza